# Ways to add one more day to the PHP code by modifying the existing code

Tags: php, laravel, datetimepicker

```
    public function doctorToday(Request $request){
        $doctors = Appointment::with('doctor')->whereDate('date',date('Y-m-d'))->get();
        return $doctors;
```

May I know how to implement one more day to the code? I want to get the tommorow's date instead of today's.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to replace `date('Y-m-d')` by `Carbon::now()->addDays($days)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692600/add-days-to-date-in-laravel, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504774/laravel-how-to-add-days-to-datetime-field and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962735/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-a-date

Comment: thanks everyone! I found the solution already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Carbon instead of `date()`.

```
public function doctorToday(Request $request){
    $doctors = Appointment::with('doctor')->whereDate('date',Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
    return $doctors;
```

don't forget to add the use statement at the start of the class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function doctorToday(Request $request){
        $doctors = Appointment::with('doctor')->whereDate('date',date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 days')))->get();
        return $doctors;
```

you need to add strtotime('+1 days')

this should work

Comment: thank you for your help! it works ! btw I think there is a missing ')' over there, before the get

Comment: yea i did, my bad. thanks gert for the edit